# If we divide a group and a proper subgroup of this group by the same normal subgroup, can the quotients be equal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a proper subgroup of $G$. Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of both $G$ and $H$.

> **Question**: Is it possible that $G/N = H/N$?

**Motivation**: For a finite extension $L/K$ of local fields, we have exact sequences

$$\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ #1\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\ras}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ \smash{#1}\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\bigg\downarrow\raise.5ex\rlap{\scriptstyle#1}}
\begin{array}{c}
1& \ra{} & I_L & \ra{} & G_L & \ra{} & \operatorname{Gal}(L^{ur}/L) & \ra{} & 1 & & \\
&  & \da{} &  & \da{} &  & \da{} & & & & \\
1 & \ra{} & I_K & \ra{} & G_K & \ra{} & \operatorname{Gal}(K^{ur}/K) & \ra{} & 1\\
\end{array}$$
We always have $\operatorname{Gal}(L^{ur}/L) = \operatorname{Gal}(K^{ur}/K) \simeq \hat{\mathbb{Z}}$. If $L/K$ is totally ramified, we have $I_L = I_K$ and I would love to conclude that $G_L = G_K$. But I am not sure whether this is possible or not.

Could you please help me resolving this problem? Thank you!

Comment: You can have groups which are isomorphic to proper subgroups(integers, free group on two generators), so for N trivial you get the result. Can you apply the five lemma in the motivating example(or are the isomorhism you talk about not compatible with the exact sequences.

Comment: Do you mean isomorphic or equal? For equality, the answer is trivially no. For isomorphism, you might as well assume that $N=1$, and then you are asking whether a group can be isomorphic to a proper subgroup, and then you can take an example like $\mathbb{Z}$ and any of its proper non-trivial subgroups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. That $g\in G$, and  $G/N \equiv H/N$ would imply that the coset $gN \subset H$, so that $g\in H$. This for all $g$.